# Boost Write XML Wrong Encoding

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I want to write a boost `wptree` to an file.
With the current `std::locale` on my Windows, set to `C` some parts of the output xml File looks like this:

```
<demo>
    <demostring1>Abc</demostring1>
    <demostring2>abc&gt;def</demostring2>
</demo>
```

But i want that the output looks like this:

```
<demo>
    <demostring1>Abc</demostring1>
    <demostring2>abc>def</demostring2>
</demo>
```

This is the Code to write the `wptree` to the file:

```
boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml(wstringToString(filename), mainTree,
    std::locale(),
    boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::wstring>(' ', 4));
```

I tried to change the locale via

```
boost::property_tree::xml_parser::write_xml(wstringToString(filename), mainTree,
    std::locale("en_US.UTF-8"), // Give an Exception on runtime.
    boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::wstring>(' ', 4));
```

How can i change the Locale so that the symbols are printed correctly in the XML file?

Comment: That has nothing to do with locales.

Comment: "How can I fribbnibble the flux capacitor so that the symbols are emitted broken as described"? Locales have nothing to with things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But i want that the output looks like this:

So you want to have invalid XML. https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-CharData

Aside from the fact that Boost doesn't really have an XML library, you won't find a non-broken XML library that does what you describe.

If you insist, you'll have to concatenate strings manually.